# Sequence of coordinates on a polygon

Tags: analytic-geometry

If we have all coordinates of the vertices of an arbitrary polyhedron, is it possible to determine on what faces they are and in what order?

Actually, I already know the first part of the question, because I did it using  linear programming. Therefore, what I really need to determine is the order of the vertices on each face. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the polyhedron is non-convex, then no:  Take the four vertices of a tetrahedron and add a fifth vertex inside their convex hull.